# Why can Magento 2 only uninstall composer packages

Tags: magento2, module, composer, uninstall

When you run `bin/magento module:uninstall Vendor_Module -r` and `Vendor_Module` happens te be a module that's not installed by Composer, Magento will not perform an uninstall.

Why did Magento add this constrain? Why am I not allowed for my own domain-specific modules to add uninstall scripts?